# How do I prevent content from being pushed up and being hidden by the mobile browser's status bar on initial page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-website, mobile-chrome

The navbar of my mobile web page seem to be being pushed up on page load after a div farther down the page finishes loading images from a CDN and summarily increasing the height of that element. I should note that I'm not 100% certain this is the cause. I've considered setting a default height on the image container that's the same height as the expected the image, but that seems like a brittle solution that would break as soon as we decide to change the image for a new one.

Anyone have any ideas on what I can do to prevent my page content from getting pushed up behind the mobile browser status bar?

Comment: Hey Gabe, please give us a reproducable example to test and more info on the specific browser and device that is creating the issue.